# Show a model of $\mathbf{Q}$ where this is false $\forall x \forall y (x \cdot y = y \cdot x) $

Tags: logic, meta-math, metalogic

> Show that there are models of $\mathbf{Q}$ where the following sentence is false
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \forall x \forall y (x \cdot y = y \cdot x) \\
> \end{align*}

For reference, the ten finite axioms of $\mathbf{Q}$ are as follows. Presume $\forall x \forall y$ for all the following; the universal quantifiers are omitted for simplicity.

\begin{align*}
  (Q1) & & \mathbf{0} \neq x' \\
  (Q2) & & x' = y' \implies x = y \\
  (Q3) & & x + \mathbf{0} = x \\
  (Q4) & & x + y' = (x + y)' \\
  (Q5) & & x \cdot \mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0} \\
  (Q6) & & x \cdot y' = (x \cdot y) + x \\
  (Q7) & & \lnot x < 0 \\
  (Q8) & & x < y' \leftrightarrow (x < y \lor x = y) \\
  (Q9) & & \mathbf{0} < y \leftrightarrow y \neq \mathbf{0} \\
  (Q10) & & x' < y \leftrightarrow (x < y \land y \neq x') \\
\end{align*}

My first intuition is to use the compactness theorem. But that doesn't seem to work. Any hints on what I can try?

Comment: How about the countable ordinals? $2\cdot\omega\ne \omega\cdot 2$.

Comment: Compactness is really only useful for showing the satisfiability of an *infinite* set of axioms; since $\mathsf{Q}$ is already finite, there isn't any good way to apply compactness here. You need to think about a specific construction.